# Exception thrown at (ntdll.dll) in Parser.exe: Access violation reading location

Tags: c, access-violation

So, this is the chapter that is bugging me so far

```
void CNCread(fPointer){
    printf("\n");
    fPointer = fopen ("CNCG.txt", "r");
    char line[30];
    while(!feof(fPointer)){
        fgets( line, 150, fPointer);
        puts(line);
    }
    fclose (fPointer);
    return;
}
```

i get the following error after compiling, running and executing this function:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCA1DEEAC5 (ntdll.dll) in Parser.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

i just converted this project from Code::Blocks to Visual Studio 2015, added legacy_stdio_definitions.lib and etc so thats not the problem either, but the code worked fine with code::blocks.
Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: `char line[30]` -- `fgets(line, 150...` -- Trying to stuff 10 pounds of potatoes into a 5 pound bag?

Comment: The obvious error is that your character array is too small and causes undefined behavior if the line is > 30 characters, but there could be other issues, so please post a [mcve].  Also, I am not convinced you compiled this actual code using Visual Studio -- the VS 2015 `C` compiler is still C89 / 90 standard, and you can't declare variables in the middle of a function block.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: that is not true.  VS has been C89 for a long time, and it now has almost all of C99 but tgmath.h and complex.  And yes, it includes declarations mixed with code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes i just noticed that error, forgot changing some of the values, and to add my lines are far smaller than 30 characters so that isnt the problem either, and librik is right about declarations. (and yes im really new to programming to be honest, mercy me my lords)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: VS accepts declaring variables in the middle of a C block of code, if the C source ends in cpp... No flame please, just a joke :-). But as present code contains almost all possible flaws in few lines: pass a pointer and assign the pointer itself, do not test `fopen` return value, try to write 150 chars in a buffer of size 30, does not test fgets return value, I would not be much surprised by that.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta well i feel embarrassed already . As i told earlier, im really new to programming. Thanks for warning me about thoose, but funny enough, opening the .exe file from project directory it works like a charm, but VS goes mad when i try to run with it.

Comment: It really looks like a VS problem then... Can you run a trivial *Hello world* inside VS? If you can, add this simple function and if it breaks then post the full code here or in a new question. If you cannot, try do reinstall VS

Comment: @SergeBallesta i can run VS fine, but it seems to always give errors when opening/closing txt files, maybe a clean install will solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `char line[30]` can contain maximum `30 char`s, but you are trying to write more than that into it by doing `fgets( line, 150, fPointer);`.

Also, you are not checking if `fopen` succeded or failed. And you should also check if `fgets` succeded or failed.

Also, you can declare `fPointer` inside your function, instead of having it as a funciton parameter. It should be of type `FILE *`.

```
void CNCread(/* fPointer */){
    printf("\n");
    FILE *fPointer = fopen ("CNCG.txt", "r");

    /* Check if fopen succeded */
    if (fPointer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot open file to read\n");
        /* Some code */
        return;
    }

    char line[30];
    while(!feof(fPointer)){
        /* You are writing more chars to line than its capacity */
        /* fgets( line, 150, fPointer); */
        /* Change it to write at max 30 chars to line */
        if (fgets( line, 30, fPointer) != NULL)
            puts(line);
    }
    if (fclose(fPointer) == EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot close the file after reading\n");
        /* Some code */
        return;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: i get so many errors in this code, which i believe im missing some includes, should i add anything more than stdio.h stdlib.h, string.h; NULL, EOF and stderr gives me errors

Comment: `stdio.h` is all you should need for what is in this function. However, there were some mistakes earlier in my code. I have corrected them. Can you check now?

Comment: i still get errors in your code, but i changed a few things, i still get the errors in the title while using vs, but it works fine with my .exe, so this is as close as it gets to right for me. thanks!

Comment: @Ata Do you mean you are still getting `Access violation reading location` error whle using the code in vs?

Comment: Yes, however it works fine when i execute the exe file from project directory, which is weird if you ask me

Comment: @ata Ok i see that you are getting errors in vs. Try to google for similar problems where a code runs fine elsewehere but not in vs. If you cant find out the reason, maybe post a question in stackoverflow with relevant details.

Comment: @Ata: this code just fixes the errors of your original one. Post a true [mcve], that is a complete (eventually simplified) source file, if you want more help/

Comment: @sps will do sir! so far it runs fine with code::blocks, runs fine on itself (by running the exe file) fine, but vs gives me error over error. have a nice day! and thanks again